# Method to combining both upload and submit - react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a solution in which uploading and submitting files can be done at the same time. I've already looked online for many resources, but they don't seem to use the form format as part of submission and label instead. I understand that you have to hide the input and create a function to click input instead, I'm just not sure where to start. How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const TicketsUpload = () => {

const [fileData, setFileData] = useState();

  const fileChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setFileData(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", fileData);
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/image", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
    })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("File Sent Successful");
        toast.success("File Sent Successfully!");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React App File Uploading</h1>
      <form id = "form" onSubmit={onSubmitHandler} encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input  id="file" type="file" onChange={fileChangeHandler} />
        <hr></hr>
        <button  className="btn btn-success" type="submit">
          Upload Ticket
        </button>
      </form>
   </div>
  );
}
export default TicketsUpload;
```

This is what I currently receive:

[image]

But I just want the 'Upload Ticket' to do both select file and upload, like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use javascript, only css is needed.

See below

```css
.fileContainer >input{
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
opacity:0;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.fileContainer>span{
background:green;
cursor:default;
padding:5px;
z-index:9;
}
```

```html
<div class="fileContainer">
<span> Upload ticket</span>
<input type="file" />
</div>
```

Comment: This makes the whole page, clickable for some reason. Meaning any part of the website would open upload file.

Comment: How can that happen? Add width and height to the file container then. Let's say 130/20 should work.